# Basics of Linux kernel versioning string

Tags: linux

I was playing around with uname -a command and i got a doubt with the info it is dumping in the console:

```
Linux 2.6.32 #1 SMP Mon May 25 18:37:58 PDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Google gave me answers for all except '#1' near SMP. I have also seen various numbers like #5  , #23 etc. Does that has any significance.

Comment: did you go trough `man uname`?

Comment: Yeah, using that only i framed the question,on the logic behind kernel version method. (uname -v). Did i missed anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same string exists as `/proc/sys/kernel/version`.

The [`proc(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) manpage states:

> This file contains a string like:
>
> ```
> #5 Wed Feb 25 21:49:24 MET 1998
> ```
>
> The "#5" means that this is the fifth kernel built from this
>   source base and the date behind it indicates the time the
>   kernel was built.

This string is ultimately defined in the [`mkcompile_h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/scripts/mkcompile_h) build script. There, you can see that in addition to the version number and date stamp, it can contain SMP and/or PREEMPT to indicate the kernel was built with these options. The version number in `.version` is initialized or incremented in [`Makefile`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Makefile?v=2.6.32) in 2.6, and was eventually moved to [`link-vmlinux.sh`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/scripts/link-vmlinux.sh).

Comment: That is perfect and i have verified it also. Thank you